# Не работает JQuery в проекте ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Есть Html-хелпер, который генерирует элемент input

```
    @Html.TextBox("message_content")
```

Пытаюсь просто изменить его цвет с помощью JQuery

```
<script>$("#message_content").css("color", "red");</script>
```

Но безуспешно.Так же скрипт после вызова функции JQuery дальше не выполняется

В **Layout** подключил все необходимые скрипты

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.Проблема была в том, что ссылки на скрипты в Layout были за пределами тега head.Хотя это тоже очень странно, т.к. у меня в других проектах эти ссылки находятся в конце файла и все отлично работает

Comment: Разместите в конце файла ссылки на библиотеки. После них разместите `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)`, все скрипты на страницах размещайте в `@section scripts`